# getElementsByTagName returns 0-length list when called from didFinishLoad delegate

Tags: c++, dom, webkit

I'm using the Chromium port of WebKit on Windows and I'm trying to retrieve a list of all of the images in my document.  I figured the best way to do this was to implement `WebKit::WebFrameClient::didFinishLoading` like so:

```
WebNodeList list = document->getElementsByTagName(L"img");
for (size_t i = 0; i < list.length(); ++i) {
  // Manipulate images here...
}
```

However, when this delegate fires, `list.length()` returns 0.  The only times I've seen it return a list of non-zero length is when I substitute "body" or "head" for "img".  Strangely enough, if I call `getElementsByTagName(L"img")` *outside* of the delegate, it works correctly.

I'm guessing that the DOM isn't fully loaded when `didFinishLoading` is called, but that would seem to contradict the delegate's name.  Does anyone know what I may be missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the mistake was purely on my side.  I was caching a pointer to the DOM document in my frame wrapper.  Of course, since a frame can outlive a DOM document, I ended up referencing an out-of-date document once I loaded a new page.